# menu for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, menu

I found good menu (Ace Responsive Menu Plugin), styled and it looks very good .It for desktop works fine but for mobile devices very bad: I mean expanded view on tablet (fast slide up on tap). Collapsed version working good. I'm not good at javascript and think it's not big problem for who know javascript.

Please help to solve this problem.

https://github.com/samsono/Ace-Responsive-Menu

```js
/* 
Ace Responsive Menu Plugin
Version: 1.0
Author: Samson.Onna 
Email : samson3d@gmail.com
----------------------------------------*/

(function ($) {
    $.fn.aceResponsiveMenu = function (options) {

        //plugin's default options
        var defaults = {
            resizeWidth: '768',
            animationSpeed: 'slow',
            accoridonExpAll: false
        };

        //Variables
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options),
            opt = options,
            $resizeWidth = opt.resizeWidth,
            $animationSpeed = opt.animationSpeed,
            $expandAll = opt.accoridonExpAll,
            $aceMenu = $(this),
            $menuStyle = $(this).attr('data-menu-style');

        // Initilizing        
        $aceMenu.find('ul').addClass("sub-menu");
        $aceMenu.find('ul').siblings('a').append('<span class="arrow "></span>');
        if ($menuStyle == 'accordion') { $(this).addClass('collapse'); }

        // Window resize on menu breakpoint 
        if ($(window).innerWidth() <= $resizeWidth) {
            menuCollapse();
        }
        $(window).resize(function () {
            menuCollapse();
        });

        // Menu Toggle
        function menuCollapse() {
            var w = $(window).innerWidth();
            if (w <= $resizeWidth) {
                $aceMenu.find('li.menu-active').removeClass('menu-active');
                $aceMenu.find('ul.slide').removeClass('slide').removeAttr('style');
                $aceMenu.addClass('collapse hide-menu');
                $aceMenu.attr('data-menu-style', '');
                $('.menu-toggle').show();
            } else {
                $aceMenu.attr('data-menu-style', $menuStyle);
                $aceMenu.removeClass('collapse hide-menu').removeAttr('style');
                $('.menu-toggle').hide();
                if ($aceMenu.attr('data-menu-style') == 'accordion') {
                    $aceMenu.addClass('collapse');
                    return;
                }
                $aceMenu.find('li.menu-active').removeClass('menu-active');
                $aceMenu.find('ul.slide').removeClass('slide').removeAttr('style');
            }
        }

        //ToggleBtn Click
        $('#menu-btn').click(function () {
            $aceMenu.slideToggle().toggleClass('hide-menu');
        });


        // Main function 
        return this.each(function () {
            // Function for Horizontal menu on mouseenter
            $aceMenu.on('mouseover', '> li a', function () {
                if ($aceMenu.hasClass('collapse') === true) {
                    return false;
                }
                $(this).off('click', '> li a');
                $(this).parent('li').siblings().children('.sub-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp($animationSpeed).removeClass('slide').removeAttr('style').stop();
                $(this).parent().addClass('menu-active').children('.sub-menu').slideDown($animationSpeed).addClass('slide');
                return;
            });
            $aceMenu.on('mouseleave', 'li', function () {
                if ($aceMenu.hasClass('collapse') === true) {
                    return false;
                }
                $(this).off('click', '> li a');
                $(this).removeClass('menu-active');
                $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp($animationSpeed).removeClass('slide').removeAttr('style');
                return;
            });
            //End of Horizontal menu function

            // Function for Vertical/Responsive Menu on mouse click
            $aceMenu.on('click', '> li a', function () {
                if ($aceMenu.hasClass('collapse') === false) {
                    //return false;
                }
                $(this).off('mouseover', '> li a');
                if ($(this).parent().hasClass('menu-active')) {
                    $(this).parent().children('.sub-menu').slideUp().removeClass('slide');
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('menu-active');
                } else {
                    if ($expandAll == true) {
                        $(this).parent().addClass('menu-active').children('.sub-menu').slideDown($animationSpeed).addClass('slide');
                        return;
                    }
                    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('menu-active');
                    $(this).parent('li').siblings().children('.sub-menu').slideUp().removeClass('slide');
                    $(this).parent().addClass('menu-active').children('.sub-menu').slideDown($animationSpeed).addClass('slide');
                }
            });
            //End of responsive menu function

        });
        //End of Main function
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* 
Ace Responsive Menu Plugin
Version: 1.0
Author: Samson Onna
E-mail: samson3d@gmail.com
----------------------------------------*/
/* Import Fonts
----------------------------------------*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

/* Ace Responsive Menu
----------------------------------------*/
a {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #0d638f;
}
ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.centered{
 display: table;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.menuholder{
 width:100%;
 background: #1067ac;  
    border-bottom: 3px solid #98d522; 
}
.ace-responsive-menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.ace-responsive-menu li{
    list-style: none;
}
.ace-responsive-menu li ul {
    display:none;
}
.ace-responsive-menu > li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0px;
    float: left;
}
.ace-responsive-menu li a {
        color:#fff;
}
.ace-responsive-menu > li > a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
}
.ace-responsive-menu li a i {
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: #FF5737;
}
.ace-responsive-menu > li > a i {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #FF5737;
}
.ace-responsive-menu li ul.sub-menu li a i {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.ace-responsive-menu li.menu-active > a {
    background: #98d522 !important;
    color:#fff;
}
.ace-responsive-menu li .menu-active {
    position: relative;
}
.ace-responsive-menu > li > a > .arrow:before {  
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    height: auto;
    content: "\f107";
    font-weight: 300;
    text-shadow: none;
    width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.ace-responsive-menu li ul.sub-menu li > a > .arrow:before {
    content: "\f105" !important;
}
.ace-responsive-menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.ace-responsive-menu li ul.sub-menu {
    background: #1067ac;
}
.ace-responsive-menu li ul.sub-menu > li {
    width: 185px;
}
.ace-responsive-menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 15px; /*12px 20px 12px 15px*/
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: none;
}
.ace-responsive-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li {
    position: relative;
}
.ace-responsive-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 185px;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
}
.ace-responsive-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li ul.sub-menu > li ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 185px;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
}
.ace-responsive-menu > li > ul.sub-menu li > a > .arrow:before {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    height: auto;
    content: "\f104";
    font-weight: 300;
    text-shadow: none;
}

/* Menu Toggle Btn
----------------------------------------*/
.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #1067ac;
}
.menu-toggle h3 {
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.menu-toggle .icon-bar {
    display: block !important;
    width: 18px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin: 3px;
}
.menu-toggle .icon-bar:hover {
    background-color: #F5F5F5 !important;
}
.menu-toggle #menu-btn {
    float: right;
    background: #98d522;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px;
}
.hide-menu {
    display: none;
}


/* Accordion Menu Styles
----------------------------------------*/

ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] {
    width: 250px;
}
ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] > li {    
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0px;
    float: none !important;
}
ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] > li:first-child {
    border-top: 2px solid #FD5025;
}
ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] li ul.sub-menu > li {
    width: 100%;
}
ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] > li > a > .arrow:before {
    float: right;
    content: "\f105";
}
ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] li.menu-active > a > .arrow:before {
    content: "\f107" !important;
}
ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] > li > ul.sub-menu {
    position: static;
}
ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] > li > a i {
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #FF5737;
}
ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] > li > ul.sub-menu > li ul.sub-menu {
    position: static;
}
ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] > li > ul.sub-menu > li ul.sub-menu > li ul.sub-menu {
    position: static;
}
ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] > li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #242424;
}
ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] li a:hover {
    background: #98d522 !important;
}
ul[data-menu-style="accordion"] ul.sub-menu li.menu-active > a > .arrow:before {
    content: "\f107" !important;
}

/* Vertical Menu Styles
----------------------------------------*/

ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] {
    width: 200px;
}
ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] > li {
    float: none;
}
ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] > li:first-child {
    border-top: 2px solid #FD5025;
}
ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] li ul.sub-menu > li {
    width: 100%;
}
ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] > li > a > .arrow:before {
    float: right;
    content: "\f105";
}
ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] > li.menu-active {
position:relative;
}
ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] > li > ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:0px;
    width:200px;
}
ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] > li > a i {
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #FF5737;
}
ul[data-menu-style="vertical"]> li > ul.sub-menu > li ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
    left: 200px;
}
ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] > li > ul.sub-menu > li ul.sub-menu > li ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
    left: 200px;
}
ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] > li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #242424;
}
ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] li a:hover {
    background: #98d522 !important;
}

/* Responsive Menu Styles
----------------------------------------*/
/*Note: change the max-width asper your requirment and change the same in aceResponsiveMenu({resizeWidth: "768" }) function*/

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .centered {
  width:98%;
    }
    ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] , ul[data-menu-style="accordion"],
    ul[data-menu-style="vertical"] li ul.sub-menu {
        width: 100% !important;
    } 
    .ace-responsive-menu {
        float: left;
        width:100%;
    }
    .ace-responsive-menu > li {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
       float: none;
    }   
    .ace-responsive-menu li a:hover {
        background: #98d522 !important;
    }
    .ace-responsive-menu > li:first-child {
        border-top: 2px solid #98d522;
    }    
    .ace-responsive-menu > li > a i {
        padding-right: 10px;
        color: #FF5737;
    }
    .ace-responsive-menu > li > a > .arrow:before {
        float: right;
        content: "\f105";
    }
    li.menu-active > a > .arrow:before {
        content: "\f107" !important;
    }
    .ace-responsive-menu li ul.sub-menu > li {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .ace-responsive-menu li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu li a
        {
        padding-left: 30px;
    }  
    .ace-responsive-menu li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu li a 
       {
        padding-left: 50px;
    }  
    .ace-responsive-menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
        position: static;
    }
    .ace-responsive-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li ul.sub-menu {
        position: static;
    }
    .ace-responsive-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li ul.sub-menu > li ul.sub-menu {
        position: static;
    }
    .ace-responsive-menu li ul.sub-menu li.menu-active > a > .arrow:before {
        content: "\f107" !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ace Responsive Menu</title>
 
 <!--Responsiveness-->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    
 <!--FontAwesome-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
    <![endif]-->
 
 <!--CSS Style-->
     <!--Scripts-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#respMenu").aceResponsiveMenu({
                 resizeWidth: '768', // Set the same in Media query       
                 animationSpeed: 'fast', //slow, medium, fast
                 accoridonExpAll: false //Expands all the accordion menu on click
             });
         });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menuholder">
    <nav class="centered">
        <!-- Menu Toggle btn-->
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <h3>Menu</h3>
            <button type="button" id="menu-btn">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Responsive Menu Structure-->
        <!--Note: declare the Menu style in the data-menu-style="horizontal" (options: horizontal, vertical, accordion) -->
        <ul id="respMenu" class="ace-responsive-menu" data-menu-style="horizontal">
             <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">About Us</a>
                <!-- Level Two-->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item One</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item Two</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item Three</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item Four</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">4 Level Menu</a>
                <!-- Level Two-->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Sub Item One</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item Two</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Sub Item Three</a>
                        <!-- Level Three-->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Link 1</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);">Sub Item Link 2</a>
                                <!-- Level Four-->
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item Link 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item Link 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item Link 3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item Four</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">Services</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item One</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Sub Item Two</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Sub Item Three       
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub Item Link 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Item Four
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="last">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem though?

Answer (score 0):

If you want mobile like look simply on tablet you can edit/override the default css from

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.centered {
        width:98%; /* for mobile*/
    }
....
}
```

to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .centered {
        width:98%; /* for tablet*/
    }
.....
}
```

and get the same behaviour on tablet as well after setting

```
$("#respMenu").aceResponsiveMenu({
                 resizeWidth: '991', // Set the same in Media query       
                 animationSpeed: 'slow', //slow, medium, fast
                 accoridonExpAll: false //Expands all the accordion menu on click
             });
```